# Is It Possible To Automatically Open Outlook Task Pane Office Add-In?

Tags: outlook, ms-office, add-in, office365, office-js

I have developed an Outlook Task Pane Office Add-in.

Is there any way to automatically load it when composing an email on the local/online versions of Office 365?

Thanks

Comment: MS said it is completed  (https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/10770030-autorun-outlook-add-ins?tracking_code=272a72cf4adf3310a7b3814b1234bce7)

Answer (score 0):

I'm also interested in knowing how to do this. We are currently exploring the options for Outlook 365 and its looking great, but ran into this issue and have not found a work around.

From what I've read they are doing something similar for Word in January but not sure it is the same for Outlook.